# Connecting to remote Site require Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection

I want to connect a website and download some data in Java, However it needs authentication. 
I searched the net and found that I should send `user:pass` to the site. I am doing it however I can not login could you give me a hint! Where is incorrect?

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.quora.com/");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty(
    "User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723  Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)"
);


String userpass = "email@xyz.com" + ":" + "password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: The code seems OK: what is the problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: are you sure quora.com uses basic authentication?

Comment: No, I am not sure that Quora.com use basic authentication. How can I detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just visited https://www.quora.com/ and it dosen't look like a basic authentication. You will need to submit a form with the HTTP type as POST with the variable names as 'email' and 'password' (You can view the source of the site and find out the expected parameters).

Looks like an AJAX mechanism is used to perform the authentication with the site. You will need to find out the page to which this request is submitted (asynchronous or otherwise).

After all this, there is a possibility that the secured connection of the site (https) may not allow you to perform the desired action (depends on SSL configuration of the server)

Comment: I used the code above to connect another site http://www.healthtap.com. Both needs authentication. I do not know why the authentication code does not work and the web server gives me the default page.